# Carrying a longboard on a Germanwings-Eurowings flight

Tags: air-travel, hand-luggage

As the title suggests, I'm interested in knowing if it is possible to board my longboard on a Eurowings flight (VRN->CGN).

I know that it is possible to carry sport equipments, but I don't know how much it will costs (neither the FAQ are clear, since they don't mention skateboards/longboards).

I'm mostly interested in carrying it onboard, almost as an hand luggage (I've already an hand-luggage and the longboard is a little bit oversized to fit).

I tried contacting via mail the assistance of Eurowings but I never ever received an answer.

So has someone references on their FAQ which clearly mention longboards/skateboards or direct experiences with Eurowings relevant to my question?

moreover, is the route relevant for this question (in the sense that it might depend on the airport)?

**PS:** Maybe it's relevant, I always do the online check-in so I just go directly to the security checks

Comment: What are the dimensions of your longboard?

Comment: @mts 96 cm length, 26 cm width, and 10 cm "height from ground"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to section 8.4.1.1.3 of the [conditions of carriage](https://www.eurowings.com/en/legal-information/general-conditions-of-carriage.html) skateboards are "blunt instruments" and are not allowed to be carried on board. I assume this extends to longboards, too.

On [Twitter Eurowings confirmed](https://twitter.com/eurowings/status/490598805944156161) that skateboards can't be carried on board. They refer to the [sport equipment](https://www.eurowings.com/en/information/services/help/questions/can-i-take-my-sports-equipment-with-me.html) page which does not mention skateboards/longboards. Other sport equipment is priced at 50 € according to the page. Likely you could also check it as regular luggage.

I have no experience though and in practice it might look different.

Comment: Thanks for the references in the FAQ. I think that as checked luggage will be my only possibility. I'll wait a little bit before accepting since I'm interested in direct experience. Thanks a lot anyway!